# SATA port confusion help

Tags: hard-drive, sata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting Internal SATA HDD to eSATA](https://superuser.com/questions/301652/connecting-internal-sata-hdd-to-esata)

On my CPU (i7 920 2.66ghz) I have 6 ports for hooking up hard drive cd/dvd etc. I believe they are referred to as or RAID eSATA (they are not IDE). However, on the back of my computer (usb/tv adapter etcc..) there are 2 ports that are ORANGE, that say SATA. Currently, the cable that my hard drive came with does not fit in the ORANGE SLOT! I am confused on what the differences are, my goal is to connect my hard drive to he ORANGE SLOT. I posted some pictures so you guys can see what I am dealing with:

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting Internal SATA HDD to eSATA](http://superuser.com/questions/301652/connecting-internal-sata-hdd-to-esata) also see [Difference between SATA and eSATA](http://superuser.com/questions/30019/difference-between-sata-and-esata)

Answer (score 3):

> So on my CPU (i7 920 2.66ghz) I have 6 ports for hooking up hard drive

Sounds like your *motherboard* (which has a socket for the CPU) has six SATA ports.  Make sure your BIOS has these ports properly configured (e.g. not RAID).

The orange colored ports are [eSATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#eSATA) ports for hot-plugging SATA devices.

For your PC's internal drives, use the six SATA ports.  For external drives, obtain an eSATA cable.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! The main problem I am having is trying to use an external hard drive for my computer (yes I know its slow). Where could I get drivers for the external hard drive to work? Thanks

Comment: @user97625 - what kind of interface does this "external hard drive" have (USB 3.0 or USB 2.0 or eSATA or Firewire 400 or 800)?  Do you already have the cable?  What OS is installed on this PC (although most mainstream OSes should be able to connect most external HDs without installation of additional drivers)?  Note that if the HD is not powered through the interface cable (e.g. a 3.5" drive on USB), then you must have the HD fully powered up using an external power source before you make the connection with the PC.

Comment: My problem is that none of the ports on my computer for the sata cable are working (i tried another hard drive and at bios settings the computer dint acknowledge it). So what I would like to do is have an external hard drive take the place of a hard drive. I have an 8gb compact flash, Im not sure if I can do it that way. If you recommend any external hard drives that work well, please recommend!

Comment: @user97625 - You seem to have a computer problem for which you have provided very little details.  You seem to be coming up with possible "solutions" or workarounds, but then don't know how to accomplish those "solutions".  So you ask how to perform each "solution" by posting questions here.  I'm not convinced that answering all of these questions is really solving the root problem; that is, I'm not convinced that you're trouble shooting this properly.  Six dead SATA ports is a serious problem; how did that happen?  Is this the first time you're putting a computer together?