# How to check if my eSATAp port provides 12V power?

Tags: hard-drive, power, esata

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Edge 13" model 0217-2QG with eSATAp port.

How do i check if my port provides 12V power (enough to power a 3.5" HDD)?

Comment: It *probably* does not provide enough power for a 3.5: HDD. If it does I am sure that it would be written in large bold letters in the manual.  The only laptop I have encountered which provides real powered eSATA is the Dell E6500. That one yields enough to power small things such as a throttle pendrive. It does not provide enough too spin up a 7200 RPM, 600mWatt external 2.5 inch drive, I let alone a 3.5 inch drive.

Comment: There is no info in the manual, if there was I wouldn't ask about it..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An eSATAp(also known as Power over eSATA, Power eSATA, eSATA/USB Combo, eSATA USB Hybrid Port (EUHP) port combines the 4 pins of the USB 2.0 (or earlier) port, the 7 pins of the eSATA port, and *optionally* two 12-volt power pins.[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#eSATA)

---

[image: eSATA port]    __________eSATA port  ____________[image: eSATA pinout]

[image: USB port]    _______________USB port______________________ [image]

[image] eSATAp [image]

[image] _____________eSATAp on notebook
___________________  [image]

---

> There are two versions of this port. Most laptop computers do not have
>   +12V power available, and have an eSATAp port which provides only +5 V. Desktop computers, with +12V available, have a port with two
>   additional pads, placed against the plug's "horns", which provide +12
>   V. Some devices, such as 2.5-inch drives, can operate off the +5V
>   supplied by laptop eSATAp ports. Others, such as 3.5-inch drives, also
>   require +12V; they can be powered from a desktop eSATAp port, but
>   require an external +12V power supply if used with a laptop computer.
>   This can lead to confusion if users are not aware of the
>   distinction.[[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESATAp#.2B12_V_issue)

**How to check if my eSATAp port provides 12V power?**

To know if your eSATAp can supply 12v or no, check the existence of P12 and P13 pins inside the port as it showing in the pictures.

Also you  can probe P12 and P13  using DMM(Digital multimeter)

[This link](http://www.addonics.com/technologies/euhp.php) provides more detailed information about eSATAp.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, my laptop doesn't have P12 & P13. (But the port looks more like eSATAp over the "eSATAp on notebook")