# eSATAp and 3.5'' HDD

Tags: hard-drive, esata

Are the red ports below eSATAp that can power a 3.5'' HDD?

[image: esatap]

I saw [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/435738/how-to-check-if-my-esatap-port-provides-12v-power) about 12V eSATAp and I would guess that they are. However I have a cable like this:
[image: cable]

which claims to support 3.5'' drives on 12V, but the disk does not even start spinning. I'm trying to understand if the cable is faulty or the port is not the one I think it is (the disk works fine, by the way).

Comment: I saw that question and referenced it in my post, but I'm not sure whether *this* port has 12V out. The shape looks correct, but I'm not sure how to check. It's also a desktop computer, not a laptop, which makes me think (according to that same post) that it should give 12V.

Answer (score 1):

On second thought, and with a better picture (below), I can now see that there is no pin 12/13 in my port, which I guess means that it's an eSATA rather than an eSATAp port. That means that I cannot connect a 3.5'' drive without external power. Shame.

[image]